Why it's not true that every function object has a `prototype` property?
I'm trying to understand some details of the following statement:

constructor is a pre-defined [[DontEnum]] property of the object pointed to by the prototype property of a function object and will initially point to the function object itself.

Intuitively, I was trying to rephrase it like this:

Every function object has a prototype property that points to a special object by default. The object has a constructor property (a pre-defined [[DontEnum]] property), which points back to the function object.

But I was told this was wrong. Why? Is it only because we can directly set it to null after creation?

You can set it to null after you created the function, sure, but there's also functions that don't have a .prototype property to begin with. Most notably, arrow functions and methods (created from method definitions in object literals or classes), but also any builtin function/method that is not meant to serve as a constructor.
